# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

when I add new Fragment(blank) I have an unresolved error in Gradle syncing. it happens even in new project. my android studio is v4.0.1. I update it recently.

this is my Gradle code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.navigationdemo"
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
 implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
 implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
 implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
 implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
 implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

 // navigation component
 implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
 implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'
}
```

and this is error that occurs [Could not resolve androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwHHO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I comment on the dependency line my app work. I found this that tell about the legacy dependency
[What is the use of androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4: dependencie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484016/what-is-the-use-of-androidx-legacylegacy-support-v4-dependencie)